# SharePoint 2013 Powershell scripts running only from C drive

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, powershell-3.0

I am able to run power shell scripts successfully by giving the path of C drive.
But the same scripts are giving error messages when executed from any other drive like D or E drive.

What settings should I change to execute them from any drive other than C drive.

Comment: if it's a management shell, change drive, then execute

Comment: can you post the error message ?